# How to replace word which are after match?

Tags: regex, performance, bash, optimization

I have this code to replace a word in file:

```
function replace_str {
    echo "${1//${2}/${3}}"
}

myfile=$(cat input.txt)
myfile=$(replace_str "$myfile" 'banana' 'stackoverflow')
echo "$myfile"
```

Then, with this content in input.txt:

```
banana
poop
poop
poop
banana
START123
poop
banana
banana
poop
START 6yu
poop
banana
```

The result is the following:

```
stackoverflow
poop
poop
poop
stackoverflow
START123
poop
stackoverflow
stackoverflow
poop
START 6yu
poop
stackoverflow
```

And what I'm looking for is to replace all `banana` word which are after the first `^START.*` match. This is the desired output:

```
banana
poop
poop
poop
banana
START123
poop
stackoverflow
stackoverflow
poop
START 6yu
poop
stackoverflow
```

What would be the most efficient way to do it? I thought in cut the file, replace it, and merge it again, but I think is not good idea.

Comment: It's not a fantastic idea to store a file into a variable and then attempt to manipulate it.  While it might a good academic exercise, it's best to avoid.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But what if I need to modify and process a lot of things after this?

Comment: @JohnDoe It's still better to do it line by line or use an external tool like `sed`, otherwise you risk a buffer overflow for large input files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed '/^START.*/,${s/banana/stackoverflow/g}' inputfile
```

This would substitute `banana` with `stackoverflow` starting from the line beginning with `START` until the end of the file.

It'd produce:

```
banana
poop
poop
poop
banana
START123
poop
stackoverflow
stackoverflow
poop
START 6yu
poop
stackoverflow
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But I used it like this: `sed "/function/,${s/$var/$foo/g}"`. But it returns: `sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unexpected ','` What I'm missing?

Comment: @JohnDoe Assuming `$var` and `$foo` are declared correctly, you probably just need to escape `${` otherwise [tag:bash] will try to expand it before `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

Quickest change to your script would probably just be to loop over the file. Something like

```
#!/bin/bash
function replace_str {
    echo "${1//${2}/${3}}"
}

match="START"
found=
while read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ ^"$match" ]] && found=:
  [[ -n $found ]] && echo "$(replace_str "$line" 'banana' 'stackoverflow')" || echo "$line"
done < input.txt
```

Sample output

```
> ./abovescript
banana
poop
poop
poop
banana
START123
poop
stackoverflow
stackoverflow
poop
START 6yu
poop
stackoverflow
```